# PHP - Getting the "failed to open stream: Permission denied " error after setting ownership

Tags: php, email, pear

I am trying to user pear's mail class, but my script does not have the permissions to access the Mail.php in my home folder where it installed, and I have properly executed the chown command on the file that it needs access to, here is what my php script looks like:

```
<?php

require_once "/home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear/Mail.php";

if (isset($_GET['trade']))
{
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Warning:  require_once(/home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear/Mail.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/newslookup/email.php on line 5
Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear/Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/newslookup/email.php on line 5
```

Here is to show that I have pear installed and I have executed the chown command properly:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-218 ~]$ pwd
/home/ec2-user

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-218 ~]$ sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache pear   // here 

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-218 ~]$ ls -alrt
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user  231 Jul 27  2018 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user  193 Jul 27  2018 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user   18 Jul 27  2018 .bash_logout
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root       22 Jan 29 02:19 ..
-rw-------  1 ec2-user ec2-user 2067 Feb 17 22:24 .viminfo
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user   19 Mar 25 20:44 .local
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user   22 Mar 25 20:44 .config
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user   22 Mar 25 20:44 .cache
drwx------  2 ec2-user ec2-user   80 Mar 25 21:49 .ssh
-rw-------  1 ec2-user ec2-user 9997 Apr 11 18:50 .bash_history
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user  611 Apr 12 14:18 .pearrc
drwx------  8 ec2-user ec2-user  193 Apr 12 14:18 .
drwxrwxr-x 10 ec2-user apache    122 Apr 12 14:19 pear  // as you can see my pear folder has the correct permissions.

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-218 ~]$ cd pear
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-218 pear]$ ls
bin  cfg  data  docs  man  php.ini-gopear  share  tests  www

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-218 pear]$ cd share
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-218 share]$ ls
pear

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-218 share]$ cd pear
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-218 pear]$ ls -alrt
total 108
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user apache    18 Apr 12 14:18 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user apache   108 Apr 12 14:18 .channels
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user apache    21 Apr 12 14:18 Archive
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user apache    24 Apr 12 14:18 Console
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user apache    36 Apr 12 14:18 Structures
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user apache    22 Apr 12 14:18 XML
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user apache    23 Apr 12 14:18 OS
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache 20562 Apr 12 14:18 System.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache  1049 Apr 12 14:18 peclcmd.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache 35467 Apr 12 14:18 PEAR.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache 15052 Apr 12 14:18 pearcmd.php
drwxrwxr-x 11 ec2-user apache  4096 Apr 12 14:18 PEAR
drwxrwxr-x  5 ec2-user apache   214 Apr 12 14:21 .registry
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user apache   126 Apr 12 14:21 Mail
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache     0 Apr 12 14:21 .lock
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache  7542 Apr 12 14:21 .filemap
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache     0 Apr 12 14:21 .depdblock
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache  2727 Apr 12 14:21 .depdb
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec2-user apache  9878 Apr 12 14:40 Mail.php    // Mail.php should be accessible by my script. 
drwxrwxr-x 11 ec2-user apache   282 Apr 12 14:40 .
```

The script is run via JavaScript, by clicking on a button.

Can anyone tell my why I would be getting the permissions error after executing the chown command?

Comment: Try setting the permissions to 755: chmod -R 755 /path/here

Comment: Hi Tim, still getting the same error.

Comment: The webserver user doesn't have any permissions to your home dir, and why should it?  Put the file in webroot or somewhere else where webserver  has read permissions.

Comment: Why don't you install PEAR-related stuff where it belongs: in the web directories? I assume that you would have to provide proper permissions for the full folder tree if you refuse to move the library

Comment: Hi @BrentHeigold , I had faced a similar problem and the way I solved it was open the htdocs folder in nautilus and set the file permission to Read and Write, in root user.

Comment: Hi Nico, I moved the pear folder to   /var/www/html/pear, now I am getting the message:  require_once(/var/www/html/pear/share/pear/Mail.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/newslookup/email.php

Answer (score 3):

I'll move it down to an answer as it seems like this is the solution to your problem from double checking the log.

```
chmod -R 755 pear
```

Chmod 755 sets the 755 permission for a file. 755 means full permissions for the owner and read and execute permission for others.

In other words just because you're the owner doesn't mean you have permissions.

Comment: Hi Tim, I get  chmod: cannot access ‘ec2-user:apache’: No such file or directory.  But even after doing "sudo chmod -R 755 pear" it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try chmoding the full path to the pear folder then instead. Also make sure you chown and chmod the project folder on the server as well.

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried  "sudo chmod -755 /home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear/Mail.php"  and still get the error.